# How to set proxy for Spring AsyncRestTemplate using Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory?

Tags: java, spring, netty, kotlin

When I use a SimpleRequestFactory with my AsyncRestTemplate I can easily configure an HTTP proxy server.

I can either do (sample code in Kotlin):

```
@Bean
open fun asyncRestTemplate(): AsyncRestTemplate {
    val proxy = Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8008))

    val requestFactory = SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory().apply {
        this.setConnectTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10).toInt())
        this.setReadTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10).toInt())
        this.setProxy(proxy)
        this.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor())
    }

    return AsyncRestTemplate(requestFactory)
}
```

Or I can simply set the corresponding system properties: `-Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8008`.

However, in the moment that I switch from the `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` to a `Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory` there is no evident way to configure the proxy directly and it seems this client does not respect the system properties either.

```
val requestFactory = Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory().apply {
    this.setConnectTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10).toInt())
    this.setReadTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10).toInt())
    //this.setProxy(proxy) //???
}
```

Once I change for the netty client, I have no clue on how to make it go through the proxy.

My interest in using the netty client was that I not only wanted to make async requests, but also I wanted this to be non-blocking. I hope I'm not making a wrong assumption here.

Does anyone know how can I use a proxy server when using the `Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory` or perhaps know of an alternative non-blocking client supported by Spring that I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory.java) ([*source*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory.java)) and related classes such as [`Netty4ClientHttpRequest`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/Netty4ClientHttpRequest.java)  ([*source*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/Netty4ClientHttpRequest.java)) use [`SimpleChannelInboundHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/Netty4ClientHttpRequest.java#L33) for the channel and do not use the proxy handler.  Everything is private and unable to be overridden within the source, so there is no way to change it to support Proxies.  You would have to almost rewrite the whole thing.

You have other async client options that will work very well and allow you more configuration options.  The included Netty one is fairly basic anyway.  `OkHttpClientHttpRequestFactory` and `HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory` both let you pass in your own configured client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jayson. I will give consideration to these other clients. That being said, my interest is that the client is not only asynchronous, but also non-blocking. I may be wrong on this, but I think both OkHttp and Apache Http Components, although async, are unfortunately blocking. Right?

Comment: okHTTP does something mixed, "In OkHttp we expose a blocking API over a framed protocol" https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Concurrency

Comment: But if proxy support is required, you can't use the default `Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory` so you have to give up on non-blocking or write a new implementation.

Comment: Most apps that use non-blocking I/O use thread pools of their own to do work, and at that point you aren't participating in the same event loop as Netty anyway, so you are causing context shifts across threads and blocking in other ways.    Anyway, this is off topic from your question.

Answer (score 0):

To your interest, AsyncRestTemplate's different implementation:

SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory -> simple thread pool, blocking api, proxy supported

OkHttpClient (OkHttp3) -> blocking api, proxy supported

CloseableHttpAsyncClient -> non-blocking nio api, proxy supported

Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory -> non-blocking nio api, proxy not supported

you can visit https://github.com/wuxudong/VariousAsyncHttpClientPerformance for more details